# How is it possible to use multiple languages when making an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking into making an app and I've been researching how other iOS apps have been made in the past. Apps such as Instagram and Snapchat were written partially in Python.

I'm not entirely sure how an app made for iOS can be written in something other than just Swift. If someone could briefly explain how these languages work together in an iOS application, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: Google is very powerful. Search for your question title and you'll get plenty of resources.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the particulars of the Instagram app, but you can use any language which will compile for the ARM architecture for writing iOS apps. You need to set up Xcode to build your code and output a static library which you can then link your other Swift, C, Objective-C or C++ code against. If the language isn't included as part of clang (such as Haskell, for example), you can use a Run Script build phase to build files in that language into the library that you include in your other targets.

Comment: So is the code being executed by an idevice could be something else than swift or ObjcC?

Comment: Yes, so long as there's a compiler for that language that can output ARM machine code.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, that makes sens. Xcode support natively objc and swift as input for the compilation. But it's up to you if you want to create a compilator that generates ARM code, cause that's what is being used by idevices at the very end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is too obvious , of course you can create an iOS app using different or multiple language for example swift + objective c or you can simply build an app using c# or c++ or combination of both. In the logical part of the application is it understood that you can use other language.